# How to plot the result of crr in a competing regression model

Tags: r

```
mod <- crr(data$survival, 
          data$endpoint,  
           cov, cencode = 0,failcode = 1)
```

After propensity score matching, I had done competing risk regression to see the impact of risk factor on the outcome.

I have run the above code successfully, but I dont know how to visualize the result.

Comment: Need a [MCVE]. Use [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Please see https://www.emilyzabor.com/tutorials/survival_analysis_in_r_tutorial.html

There are examples how to deal with.